# Hide server ip using php curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I need to hide server ip in video url using this php code

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P5Pr866GMSduTPkCOWWxBG2JjgBQwPJcjwNvsWcvZIc=m37',1);
echo $headers["Location"];
?>
```

for example this reproduce

```
https://r11---sn-25g7sn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=7ac8bbe9f1252458&itag=37&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-25g7sn7k&ms=nxu&mv=m&pl=24&gir=yes&clen=2397793036&dur=8374&lmt=1428174127938611&mime=video/mp4&mt=1435163918&ip=SERVER_IP&ipbits=0&expire=1435192809&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,gir,clen,dur,lmt,mime&signature=18C960CEA0D8AAD855013B8F95DCE1BDAEC9AB9B.B5455BFDE48F57D0AB9FFE8BBDC962B7CC27B003&key=ck2
```

there is a way to mask/hide server ip in some way?

Comment: This is entirely too vague. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: in second url u can see ip=SERVER_IP, i need to hide it

Comment: The only way to hide your IP address from the internet is to unplug your computer. This is like asking "How do I erase my street address, but still get mail?"

Comment: Are you trying to obscure it from the output? By this, you want to search the string for a specific text portion, and remove it from the string?

Comment: @Twisty yes, if there is a way to replace/obscure/regex the ip with another ip it's good, but i've try, and dont work, video url work only with server ip for me :(

Comment: Again still too vague. What code have you tried? What are the conditions of this service? Does it use cookies? is it examining the header to make sure you're IP does not change. Need more details.

Comment: imjust need to use the php code file on server, but i need to hide ip in redirect url..that's all

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P5Pr866GMSduTPkCOWWxBG2JjgBQwPJcjwNvsWcvZIc=m37',1);
$parts = explode('&ip=SERVER_IP', $headers["Location"]);
echo $parts[0] . $parts[1];
?>
```

This should result in:

```
https://r11---sn-25g7sn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=7ac8bbe9f1252458&itag=37&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-25g7sn7k&ms=nxu&mv=m&pl=24&gir=yes&clen=2397793036&dur=8374&lmt=1428174127938611&mime=video/mp4&mt=1435163918&ipbits=0&expire=1435192809&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,gir,clen,dur,lmt,mime&signature=18C960CEA0D8AAD855013B8F95DCE1BDAEC9AB9B.B5455BFDE48F57D0AB9FFE8BBDC962B7CC27B003&key=ck2
```

Comment: Dont work, SERVER_IP i mean : 127.0.0.1 (for example) if i replace with something other, video url dont work :(

Comment: Ok, I refer back to my previous comment. What is the result you are getting? What is not working specifically?

Comment: the result is a blank page

Comment: Ok, what does your Redirect script look like now? If you're serious about getting an answer you should provide all the details about the issue.

Comment: What i want is this: use some php file/script uploaded on my server and get redirect url without reveal server ip, i think is possible but i dont know how :(

Comment: You can remove the IP from the URL, or from string, yet you cannot obscure the Servers IP Address when it makes a HTTP call to another. The IP is part of the header of the new request.